# Подскажите эффективный вариант пагинации postgres, который можно использовать в коммерции?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

Сразу скажу, гуглил, варианты неоднозначные. Только не limit с offset. И что бы его можно было воспроизвести с помощью ORM.

Comment: давайте вы свои неоднозначные варианты опишите с их минусами вместе, чтобы был предмет разговора. Подозреваю, что без limit будет несколько сложно обойтись, по крайней мере, если вы хотите получить Nное число записей на страницу. В целом, если вы хотите делать пагинацию например по дате, то обрезать надо не по номеру страницы и лимиту, а по дате и лимиту. То есть на вход передавать дату последнего имеющегося, и фильтровать от нее в where, соответственно имея соответствующий индекс в БД.

Comment: Если счетчик общего числа страниц не нужен, то из базы можно вернуть N+1 запись. Если вернулось столько, значит есть следующая страница. Если <= N то эта страница последняя. Отдавать на фронт конечно, в любом случае надо N, а не N+1. Это вас избавит от запроса на count. Но в целом если результаты такого подсчета кэшировать, то особого смысла это не имеет.

Comment: Какая ORM? Какой язык программирования? / Например, в ORM Entity Framework (C#) можно использовать как Offset, так и [Keyset pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination#keyset-pagination)

Comment: [We need tool support for keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)